# Div appearing is moving nephew div (parents child)

Tags: jquery

In my header I have a button that displays an option box underneath when you hover over it. Underneath the header is the main page. However, when I open the options by hovering over the button, the page's content lowers down to go under the div.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Minecraft_Percabeth/xr7dcf3f/30/

jsfiddle fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/Minecraft_Percabeth/xr7dcf3f/30/embedded/result/

This is the menu that appears:

```
#blogs {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #60AD32;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: -25px;
```

Is there anything I need to add to it? To make other divs ignore it? The float:right; makes it so the main page div ignores it, but its content does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your UL for blogs inside the div "right".

Change your CSS class for blogs to have position : absolute; and remove the margin-top setting.

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xr7dcf3f/34/

Here is the HTML change

```
    <div class='right blogs-menu'>
        <div class='button blog'>                 
            <h2>Blogs</h2>
        </div>
        <ul id='blogs'>
            <p>< James</p>
            <p>< Jeremiah</p>
            <p>< Peter</p>
            <p>< Thomas</p>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and the css change

```
#blogs {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #60AD32;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful as well, but could you explain something? I have the header set to overflow: hidden; so why does it not expand when the blog list shows up? This usually happens to me, but not in your example. Is it because of the position: absolute? I'd love to know because I run into that problem a lot.

Comment: Yes, position: absolute is why it is not effected by the header's overflow: hidden setting. Take a look at http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101 and http://learnlayout.com/position.html . They both have great explanations of position and how different position settings work together. Absolute positioning allows you to offset from the nearest positioned ancestor and also breaks out of the normal document flow.

Comment: Thank you for the links, they've been helpful. I'll try my best to remember it all.

Comment: Would you throw out some up votes for helpful material?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using the `position` and `z-index` css attributes.

```
#blogs {
    float: right;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background-color: #60AD32;
    border-radius: 7px;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#jumbo {
    padding-top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #1B7523;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr7dcf3f/33/)

Comment: Interesting. What does z-index do in this case?

Comment: z-index is in a sense which layer the object is on. by setting it to 1, where everything else defaults to 0, it moves to the front. Using z-index requires a position attribute unfortunately though.